# Cambiar icono en kml para Google Earth

Tags: google-maps

he estado intentado realizar un archivo kml para Google Earth donde se muestre un punto determinado en el mapa. He intentado cambiar el icono (en vez de la chincheta amarilla que aparezca otro) con el siguiente código, pero no lo he conseguido:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
 <Style id="icono">
  <IconStyle>
   <Icon>
    <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon28.png</href>
   </Icon>
  </IconStyle>
 </Style>
 <Folder>
  <Placemark>
   <name>name</name>
   <description>descrip</description>
   <styleUrl>#icono</styleUrl>
   <Point>
    <coordinates>lon,lat</coordinates>
   </Point>
  </Placemark>
 </Folder>
</kml>
```

¿Que tendría que modificar para poder cambiar dicho icono? Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se diría que lo único que te falta es la etiqueta `<Document>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
 <Document>
   <Style id="icono">
    <IconStyle>
     <Icon>
      <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon28.png</href>
     </Icon>
    </IconStyle>
   </Style>
   <Folder>
    <Placemark>
     <name>name</name>
     <description>descrip</description>
     <styleUrl>#icono</styleUrl>
     <Point>
      <coordinates>-3.6955,40.4276</coordinates>
     </Point>
    </Placemark>
   </Folder>
 </Document>
</kml>
```

```js
 function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: {lat: 40.40, lng: -3.6955}
        });

        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: 'http://www.ffflabs.com/cctv7.kml?0',
          map:map,
          preserveViewport:true
        });
        
        
      }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map {
 height:600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyBRqo4qwqHHrtbY9aL6vYYDw1GOhkK97MQ"></script>
<div id="map">
```